netlify deployment issue, the function is not running post static deploy
I got this running great locally on ngrok. I am having issues both deploying on netlify now. This file lives in netlify/functions folder and is named api.js. I am using a telegram bot and when i communicate start to it it does not work. i am also using a database to post scores with ngrok it works perfectly.
this is the neftify.toml file
  functions = "netlify/functions"  # This tells Netlify where your serverless functions are located
  publish = "public"               # This tells Netlify to serve the 'public' folder for static files

[[redirects]]
  from = "/api/*"                  # Redirect API requests to the appropriate serverless function
  to = "/.netlify/functions/:splat"
  status = 200

every time i go to run the bot typing /start... nothing happens both on dev and post deploy
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); // MongoDB connection
const serverless = require('@netlify/functions'); // Netlify serverless handler
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Score = require('../../models/Score'); // Adjust the path to your model
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const token = process.env.TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN;
const url = process.env.NGROK_URL; // Using Netlify's URL for webhook

// Initialize the Telegram Bot
const bot = new TelegramBot(token);

// Set webhook with Netlify URL
(async () => {
  try {
    await bot.setWebHook(`${url}/.netlify/functions/submit-score/webhook`);
    console.log("Webhook set successfully.");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error setting webhook:", error);
  }
})();

// Initialize Express app
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Middleware to parse JSON bodies

// Connect to MongoDB
const connectDB = async () => {
  if (mongoose.connection.readyState >= 1) return; // Prevent multiple connections
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.PROD_DB_TOKEN, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
    console.log('MongoDB connected');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('MongoDB connection error:', error.message);
    throw new Error('Database connection failed');
  }
};

// State management for user interactions
const userStates = {};

// Route for Telegram to POST updates to
app.post('/webhook', async (req, res) => {
  console.log('Webhook request received');
  try {
    await connectDB(); // Ensure database is connected
    await bot.processUpdate(req.body); // Process the update
    res.sendStatus(200); // Respond OK to Telegram
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error processing webhook:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Failed to process webhook');
  }
});

// Route to handle score submissions
app.post('/submit-score', async (req, res) => {
  console.log('Submit score endpoint hit');
  await connectDB(); // Ensure database is connected
  const { score, userId } = req.body;

  try {
    const allScores = await Score.find();
    console.log('All scores in the database:', allScores);

    let existingScore = await Score.findOne({ userId });
    if (!existingScore) {
      console.log(`No existing score found for user ${userId}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Existing score for user ${userId}:`, existingScore);
    }

    if (existingScore && existingScore.score >= score) {
      const difference = existingScore.score - score;
      const message = `You already have a higher score of ${existingScore.score}. You need to beat this by ${difference} more points to update your score.`;
      await bot.sendMessage(userId, message);
      await bot.sendMessage(userId, "Try again :)");
      return res.json({ success: false, message, receivedData: req.body });
    }

    const topScores = await Score.find().sort({ score: -1 }).limit(10);
    const lowestTopScore = topScores.length < 10 ? null : topScores[topScores.length - 1].score;

    if (score > lowestTopScore || (!existingScore || score > existingScore.score)) {
      const result = await Score.findOneAndUpdate(
        { userId },
        { $set: { score } },
        { upsert: true, new: true, runValidators: true }
      );

      if (result.ethereumAddress) {
        await bot.sendMessage(userId, `Your current Ethereum address is ${result.ethereumAddress}. Would you like to update it? Reply with "yes" or "no".`);
        userStates[userId] = { score, userId, awaitingUpdate: true };
      } else {
        await bot.sendMessage(userId, `Congratulations! Your score of ${result.score} has been updated or added to the top 10. Please reply with your Ethereum address to record it.`);
        userStates[userId] = { score, userId, awaitingAddress: true };
      }

      res.json({ success: true, message: 'Score updated successfully.', receivedData: req.body });

      if (topScores.length >= 10 && score > lowestTopScore) {
        await Score.findOneAndDelete({ _id: topScores[topScores.length - 1]._id });
      }
    } else {
      const message = `Your score of ${score} did not qualify for the top 10 or beat your previous best score.`;
      res.json({ success: false, message, receivedData: req.body });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error processing score submission:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Error recording score', error: error.message });
  }
});

// Handle incoming Telegram messages
bot.on("message", async (msg) => {
  const userId = msg.chat.id;
  const userState = userStates[userId];

  try {
    if (userState && userState.awaitingAddress) {
      const ethereumAddress = msg.text;
      const { score } = userState;

      const updatedScore = await Score.findOneAndUpdate(
        { userId },
        { $set: { ethereumAddress } },
        { new: true, runValidators: true }
      );

      if (updatedScore) {
        await bot.sendMessage(userId, `Thank you! Your score of ${updatedScore.score} and Ethereum address ${updatedScore.ethereumAddress} have been recorded.`);
        delete userStates[userId];
      } else {
        await bot.sendMessage(userId, "Error updating your Ethereum address. Please try again.");
      }

      return;
    }

    if (userState && userState.awaitingUpdate) {
      if (msg.text.toLowerCase() === 'yes') {
        await bot.sendMessage(userId, "Please enter your new Ethereum address.");
        userStates[userId].awaitingAddress = true;
        delete userStates[userId].awaitingUpdate;
      } else if (msg.text.toLowerCase() === 'no') {
        await bot.sendMessage(userId, "Great! Your current Ethereum address will be used.");
        delete userStates[userId];
      }
      return;
    }

    if (msg.text.toLowerCase() === '/start') {
        await bot.sendMessage(userId, 'Welcome! Click below to check your score or submit a new one.', {
          reply_markup: {
            inline_keyboard: [[{ text: 'Open Web App', web_app: { url: url } }]]
          }
        });
      }
      
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error handling message:', error);
  }
});

// Export the app as a Netlify function
module.exports.handler = serverless(app);

i have made several attempts to restructure my repo and with my serverless function and netify.toml.
